# Safe redo (Ctrl-Y)

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In ST (Sublime Text for short) the redo action works very strange and inconvenient way, from my point of view.

First test. Type some text, for example

```
Foo
```

and then press Ctrl-Y one or several times. You will see:

```
FooFooFoo
```

Second test. Again, type something, for example

```
The cat on the roof.
```

and then press Backspace to remove the dot at the end of sentence. Okay, and then press Ctrl-Y several times. You will see:

```
The cat on the ro
```

It very differs from any text editor/IDE I have used - Brackets, Vim and some more.

Is there some way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default redo/undo keybindings in ST are:

- `ctrl+z`: `undo`
- `ctrl+shift+z`: `redo`
- `ctrl+y`: `redo_or_repeat` (explained in @MattDMo's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1065570/569470))
- `ctrl+u`: `soft_undo` this does not only undo text changes, but also cursor movements. This can be very useful if you jumped somewhere and want to go back or added a selection you did not want.
- `ctrl+shift+u`: `soft_redo`

Hence the keybinding you want ist `ctrl+shift+z`.

However if you want to map it to `ctrl+y`, you can open `Preferences >>> Keybindings - User` and paste the following:

```js
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+y"],
        "command": "redo"
    }
]
```

Comment: In Mac, use `"super+y"`.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> is not a shortcut for redo, it's a shortcut for "repeat last action". Perform some actions, then click on the `Edit` menu and see what the menu option for `^Y` says. It will most likely say something like "Repeat Insert Characters" if you've just been typing, or "Repeat Left Delete" if you've just been hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. It's meant to be used in conjunction with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or "Undo last action". For example, you select some text and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>, only to realize you selected too much. You can then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the delete, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to *repeat* the delete action.

Comment: @johnc.j. `ctrl+shift+z` is the hotkey for redo